# How to delete repeated rows if column 2 and column 3 matches using awk?

Tags: awk

I have a file with 4 columns:

```
ifile.txt
3  5  2  2
1  4  2  1
4  5  7  2 
5  5  7  1 
0  0  1  1
```

I would like to delete the repeated rows whose column 2 & 3 are same. for instance, row 3 & 4 has same values in column 2 & 3. So I wnat to keep the 3rd row and delete 4th row. my output is:

```
ofile.txt
3  5  2  2
1  4  2  1
4  5  7  2
0  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{a[NR]=$2""$3} a[NR]!=a[NR-1]{print}' file
```

Save `$2` and `$3` value to array `a` with index as `NR`. Then if value of `a` in current line and previous line doesn't match print line else ignore.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2,$3]++;next}a[$2,$3]==1' file file
3  5  2  2
1  4  2  1
0  0  1  1
```

GNU awk

Comment: Very nice. Works fine with regular (non-gawk) awk as well.

Comment: @A-Ray: Thank you very much. But I am sorry, I was looking for something else. i.e. to delete the repeated one.

Comment: like this ? `awk '![a$2,$3]++' file`